# Unity WebGL Google Analytics failed hits

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, unity-webgl

I'm currently having a bit of trouble with GA and Unity WebGL. Every time I try to submit and event I keep getting the error "Google Analytics hit request failed with error "in the JS console with no message, but the events for the first user are being recorded.

It also seems to be only registering the first user when I'm looking at the real time feed. It seems to work as expected when I build my game to iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the reason was this:
The GoogleAnalyticsV4 plugin logs the warning "Google Analytics hit request failed with error" when it didn't find a STATUS field in the response headers. However, the GA Server does not respond with that field when sending from within Unity / WebGL. The good news: Your hits will be counted anyway, as long as your request was valid. You can check your request data/url by using the [Google Test Server](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits) or the [Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/).